# Python BeautifulSoup find_all() only returns first table from html instead of all tables?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to get the tables from this website: https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bryanko01.html

My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


f = open("testhtml.txt", 'w')
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bryanko01.html"
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
totals = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in bs.find_all("table")]
print(len(totals)) # prints 1
f.write(bs.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

I write to a file to look at the raw html and there are multiple tables (with the table tags), but for some reason, my call to `find_all("table")` only returns one table.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts as to what I may be doing wrong.f

Comment: this is a javascript rendering problem, you'll have to check all the requests that are being created when visiting that url to get all the information. It doesn't come with that simple GET request.

Comment: This is because `urlopen(url)` returns you static content that has been loaded without JavaScript enabled. Just try disabling Javascript for https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/b/bryanko01.html and see you wil get only one table. To get dynamic content in your html try `selenium` or similar packages to get html content.

Comment: I see that the tables are loaded dynamically. Are you sure, that they are present, when your script tries to access them? Maybe you need a `sleep(2)` just after the `urlopen` command in order to wait for the page to be loaded.

Comment: @StegSchreck I tried including the a time.sleep(2) call right after the urlopen and it didn't seem to change anything...any other ideas?

Comment: @eLRuLL any ideas on how to check all the requests that are being created when visiting the url?

Comment: you can use Chrome's developer tools (View -> Developer -> Developer Tools) on the Network Tab. @StegSchreck suggestion is totally incorrect, `urlopen` will only make the asked request. If you really want to emulate a browser you should look into `selenium`.